# Script Runner Error 'Failed type checking'

Tags: groovy, jira

I am trying to use script runner to be able to check my scripts for any error/deprecated classes. However for a few files simply said the following error:

```
Failed type checking and we don't know why, it's our fault not yours @ line 1, column 1.
```

I've isolated the problem to the following:

```
Map tmprc = issue.getCustomFieldValue(rcObj) as Map
if (tmprc) {
    // Root Cause Category field defined but ensure both parts of its cascading field are selected
    rotCausEntered = ((tmprc.get(null) != null) && (tmprc.get("1") != null))
}
```

In particular is is the following bit of code causing the error

`(tmprc.get(null) != null)`

Just curious if anyone knows why this bit of code is causing the error. If I comment the line out everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense that this would fail in a type-checking scenario, since `null` is not a type and you're passing it to a function `get()` that expects an `Object` type parameter. For example, if you run `null instanceof Object`, it returns `false`. The type-checker probably doesn't know how to handle that and is returning the error you're seeing.

Why you are using `null` as a key in a `Map`? Changing that behavior is probably your solution.

Comment: Working off someone else's code here. It looks like it's fetching information from a custom field with two inputs in a drop-down menu. Where depending on what you select in field A you'll get new options in field B. So I'll probably bring this up with the author to double check why they do this exactly.